# Xcode 6 - Images Xcassets - Images size and devices Resolutions

Tags: xcode, xcasset

I am trying to understand what's going on with the new resolutions on all iPhones Devices (including 6,6+).
I read this one http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions but I still don't understand what's going on.
For example:
I have an image view which it should be full screen on each iPhone above iPhone 5. I created an Image Xcasset with 3 sizes: @1x, @2x and 3@x.
What image sizes should I add in Xcasset to support iPhone 5,5S,6,6+?